# Why is the word "foot" used as the basic form of poetic metre?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

Someone is making an analogy between "swift-footed Achilles" and poetic "feet". This makes me wonder why iambs, trochees, etc. are called "feet" and when this started. Can you help?

Comment: "I don't know but I've been told" that it might be something to do with [marching or dancing](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=foot) (or just keeping time in general by tapping the foot)

Comment: English prosodic terminology tends to be loaned or in this case calqued from ancient Greek, despite fundamental differences in application; and ancient Greek poetry was more tightlly associated with both singing and dancing than English poetry ever has been.

Answer (score 1):

Why? According to OED:

> In sense A. 5 (in prosody), after similar use of classical Latin pēs, ancient Greek πούς; the term is commonly taken to refer to the movement of the foot in beating time.

When? OED lists examples from Old English:

> OE   Ælfric *Gram*. (St. John's Oxf.) 290:
>    Þæra **fota** is fela: mid ðam setton *poetae*, þæt sind gelærede sceopas, heora leoðcræft on bocum.
>
> OE   Byrhtferð *Enchiridion* (Ashm.) (1995) ii. i. 90:
>   Pentimemeris byð þe todælð þæt uers on þam oðrum **fet**, and byð gemet healf fot to lafe.

(I'm not able to find a "translation" of either sentence unfortunately.)